# Saving and sharing changes made to Vagrant box

Tags: vagrant

I setup an Ubuntu 13.04 box from www.vagrantbox.es. Post that I made changes to the box - installed ruby, rails, git, mysql, ngnix, etc. How do I share the modified box with someone else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After making your changes, use `vagrant package` in the directory with the Vagrantfile. It will shut the machine down and start saving it to a file.

You'll end up with a boxfile in that directory that you can share.

Answer (score 4):

As already answered, `vagrant package` creates a new base box out of an existing VM.

Anyway "the Vagrant way" is to use and share a Vagrantfile with [provisioners](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html). This way the installation of the software is repeatable. The downside is that initial `vagrant up` takes longer while it installs all the software, but on the other hand the shared base box is smaller. Depends on your use case what is the best.

If you choose to share a pre-installed image you can still benefit from automated provisioning using e.g. [Packer](http://www.packer.io/) to build the box.

Answer (score 0):

To package existing rolled out machine, do following:

1) Get list of machines by command `VBoxManage list vms`
2) Copy name of machine and execute command `vagrant package --base {name_of_machine}`

Then .box file will be created in vagrant folder